# Fail to save pdf file using addHTML in jspdf

Tags: javascript, jspdf

Heading:

```
<head>
 <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="jspdf.min.js"></script>
 <script src="html2canvas.min.js"></script>
 <script src="jspdf.plugin.addhtml.js"></script>
</head>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div class="red b"></div>
 <div class="yellow b"></div>
 <div class="blue b"></div>
 <div class="green b"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
  pdf.addHTML($("#wrapper"), function () {
      pdf.save();
  });
});
```

I want to add the div #wrapper into the pdf file when I press the button to generate it. But then when I press the button and inspect element in Chrome, it always show an unloaded events in sources.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to do:

1. Use the first element of array returned by jQuery selector `$('#wrapper')[0]`
2. Define the name of the pdf file you want to save `pdf.save('Test.pdf');`

> ```
> $('#downloadPdf').on('click', function() {
>     var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
>
>     pdf.addHTML($('#wrapper')[0], function() {
>         pdf.save('Test.pdf');
>     });
> });
> ```

You can check [Demo Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ivangrs/y35ep2qt/)

Comment: Thanks for the demo. And I further figure out one of my problem is that the source of my "jspdf.min.js" is not updated and when I use the source in your demo, it could run properly.

Comment: Demo isn't working. I can't find `jspdf.plugin.addhtml.js` file. Can you give me cdn link?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to use just that in my code but clicking on the button that would generate the PDF does not occur at all. I wonder if it would be possible to provide the source code to power try to manipulate and implement.Thank U.